# if statement not executed

Tags: c++, if-statement, static, constants

I have problem with an if statement not being executed. The corners below are fixed, const.
Now I want a static variable alphadrone move from one corner to the other.

The first 'if' works, the second not.

**LATLON_TO_CM is 1.113195f**. I tried to put f behind every number, made all float, double, the statement don't gets executed.
This isn't logic, I put the same number into two variables (that have different names but the same datatype) and it doesn't work.

```
const int32_t corner_1_X = 47.590000 * 1e3 * LATLON_TO_CM;
const int32_t corner_1_Y = 7.646000  * 1e3 * LATLON_TO_CM; //bigger
const int32_t corner_2_X = 47.590000 * 1e3 * LATLON_TO_CM;
const int32_t corner_2_Y = 7.644000  * 1e3 * LATLON_TO_CM; //smaller

static int32_t alphadroneXposition = corner_1_X;
static int32_t alphadroneYposition = corner_1_Y;

// if (corner_1_Y > corner_2_Y)
    // moveAlphadroneYneg(&alphadroneYposition);
if (alphadroneYposition > corner_2_Y)
    moveAlphadroneYneg(&alphadroneYposition);
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example. It's impossible to say anything with the little info you provide. I'd guess integer overflow as cause of confusion though.

Comment: Defining `LATLON_TO_CM = 1`, the if executed fine here. Watch out for overflow or bad conversions.

Comment: any change in the value of `alphadroneYposition` in your code should be shared, otherwise the conditions are similar

Comment: You are aware that `int32_t` is an integer type, but you're mixing with `double` precisions that can't be represented there and simply are lost?

Comment: In my experience, ghosts like the one you're seeing were consequence of code and executable not being in sync. Try rebuilding your project (all build types, i.e. Debug, Release, etc).

Comment: If this code is in a function that is executed more than once, the initialization of static variables will only occur the first time the function is executed. After that, `alphadroneYposition` will retain its value from the previous invocation.

Comment: @M.M: this was the solution! Thanks! I decreased too much!
so much trees!

Answer (score -1):

So for some reason your code isn't saying that alphadroneYposition is greater than the corner position, even though it is a little bit bigger. I looked at it like three times myself just to confirm that yes, that first number is a little bit bigger.

alphadroneYposition = 7.646000  * 1e3

corner_2_Y = 7.644000  * 1e3

Usually this happens because of floating point precision and the errors that result from comparing two floating point numbers. Check out this related topic from stackoverflow on comparing floats.

[What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's no problem with the floating-point values you've given here. Superstition is no substitute for knowledge.